# How to open a folder containing a specific string? (Mac)

Tags: macos, find, applescript, directory

We got some folders with project IDs with the following Pattern: x123_projectname.

I use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) in my workflow and I need to find and open a specific folder by the ID. 
It is possible to run applescripts from Alfred. I'm new to applescript and google helped me to create this this:

```
set theString to "/path/to/folder/containing/projects/"
display dialog "What is the ID?" default answer ""
set theID to the text returned of 
    (display dialog "What is the ID?" default answer "")

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set x to theString & "theID" as alias
    open x
end tell
```

but it didn't work - do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems with your script but in general you have the right idea. The main problem is that applescript doesn't work with slash delimited paths. Applescript paths are colon delimited. You can convert from slash to colon delimited using the "posix file" command. Give this a try. Good luck.

```
set theString to "/path/to/folder/containing/projects/"
display dialog "What is the ID?" default answer ""
set theID to the text returned of result

set macString to POSIX file theString
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set theResult to every folder of macString whose name contains theID
    open theResult
end tell
```

Comment: Sadly this isn't working, yet. I have to something like this:
http://pastebin.com/p7suPz67

Comment: Well, you changed the parameters of your question. I updated my code to work like you want. Again you weren't using POSIX file properly. Also your "every folder" code is a Finder command so that needs to be inside the Finder tell block of code. Note I didn't test the new code but it should work.